# onblur is getting called before textbox gets updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I have a textbox for a date so the user can select the date using the datepicker.

[image]

I want to know if the date gets changed so I added an `onblur` to the textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDate" CssClass="dateonly" Width="80px" onblur="CheckIfDateChanged(this.value)" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Then in my jquery I wanted to check the date it is getting so I added an alert:

```
function CheckIfDateChanged(date)
{
   alert(date);
}
```

The `onblur` seems to get called before the textbox actually changes with the new date. So if the current date is 28/10/2016 and I change it to 29/10/2016 the alert shows 28/10/2016. Then the date changes after I close the alert message.

How do I know if the date gets changed when they select the new date from the datepicker?

Comment: When you click on `input`, it gets focus and then since its a datepicker, calendar appears and takes focus from input. Due to this, input loses focus and calls onblur

Comment: Use `onchange()` instead of `onblor()`, so whenever your text box get changed after that it will call

Comment: @BharatPatidar `onchange()` isn't working if I select the date from the datepicker. It will get called if I type in the date into the textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `onSelect` event.

```
$(".dateonly").datepicker({
  onSelect: function(date) {
    display("Date: " + this.value);
  }
});
```

Read more https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onchange` event of `textbox`. This event is fired when value of textbox is changed.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDate" CssClass="dateonly" Width="80px" onchange="CheckIfDateChanged(this.value)" ></asp:TextBox>
```

OR

you can bind event on 'onSelect` of datepciker and call your function

```
$(".dateonly").datepicker({
  onSelect: function(date) {
    alert(date);
  }
});
```

Comment: `onchange()` isn't working if I select the date from the datepicker. It will only get called if I type in the date into the textbox

Answer (score 0):

try using `onfocusout`

i've ran into similar problems myself. i just added `onfocusout` to the element attributes along with the function i wanted to call.